# simple way to get Z "depth" in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I need to detect a blue object and a red object from two different cameras, the required task for now is to locate each object position in 3D space, this means for each object we have to have its x,y,z coordinates, I've seen [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I8eKRT5N-II) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0cQXU5X0Yyk) witch does exactly what i'm trying to do but there was no sample code in case of the first video, my code looks like this for now it gets me x,y of red/blue object but no depth:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <opencv/highgui.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
//int func(int argc, char** argv)
{
    VideoCapture cap(0); //capture the video from webcam
    VideoCapture cap1(1); //capture the video from extrenal camers
    if (!cap.isOpened())  // if not success, exit program
    {
        cout << "Cannot open the web cam" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    if (!cap1.isOpened())  // if not success, exit program
    {
        cout << "Cannot open the External camera" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    namedWindow("Control", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); //create a window called "Control"

    int iLowH = 170;
    int iHighH = 179;
    int iLowS = 150;
    int iHighS = 255;
    int iLowV = 60;
    int iHighV = 255;

    //Create trackbars in "Control" window to control the range of red detection
    createTrackbar("LowH", "Control", &iLowH, 179); //Hue (0 - 179)
    createTrackbar("HighH", "Control", &iHighH, 179);
    createTrackbar("LowS", "Control", &iLowS, 255); //Saturation (0 - 255)
    createTrackbar("HighS", "Control", &iHighS, 255);
    createTrackbar("LowV", "Control", &iLowV, 255);//Value (0 - 255)
    createTrackbar("HighV", "Control", &iHighV, 255);

    int iLastX = -1;    //last known co-ordinates of red object
    int iLastY = -1;
    int iLastX1 = -1;
    int iLastY1 = -1;

    //Capture a temporary image from both cameras to obtain size
    Mat imgTmp;
    cap.read(imgTmp);
    cap1.read(imgTmp);

    //Create a black image with the size as the camera output
    Mat imgLines = Mat::zeros(imgTmp.size(), CV_8UC3);;
    Mat imgLines1 = Mat::zeros(imgTmp.size(), CV_8UC3);;

    //loop of continuously capturing frames from video
    while (true)
    {
        Mat imgOriginal;

        Mat imgOriginal1;
        bool bSuccess = cap.read(imgOriginal); // read a new frame from video webcam
        bool bSuccess1 = cap1.read(imgOriginal1); // read a new frame from video external cam

        if (!bSuccess || !bSuccess1) //if not success, break loop
        {
            cout << "Cannot read a frame from video stream" << endl;
            break;
        }
        //WebCam code for image and tracking/detecting  
        Mat imgHSV;
        cvtColor(imgOriginal, imgHSV, COLOR_BGR2HSV); //Convert the captured frame from BGR to HSV to control range of color to obtain and be able to detect it
        Mat imgThresholded;
        inRange(imgHSV, Scalar(iLowH, iLowS, iLowV), Scalar(iHighH, iHighS, iHighV), imgThresholded); //Threshold the image at the colors within specified range
        //morphological opening (removes noise and similar colored objects appearing in thresholded image)
        erode(imgThresholded, imgThresholded, getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(5, 5)));
        dilate(imgThresholded, imgThresholded, getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(5, 5)));

        //morphological closing (removes noise appearing inside our object in the thresholded image)
        dilate(imgThresholded, imgThresholded, getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(5, 5)));
        erode(imgThresholded, imgThresholded, getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(5, 5)));
        //Calculate the moments of the thresholded image to calculate the object position
        Moments oMoments = moments(imgThresholded);
        double dM01 = oMoments.m01;
        double dM10 = oMoments.m10;
        double dArea = oMoments.m00;

        // if the area <= 10000, I consider that the there are no object in the image and it's because of the noise, the area is not zero 
        if (dArea > 10000)
        {
            //calculate the position of the ball
            int posX = dM10 / dArea;
            int posY = dM01 / dArea;

            if (iLastX >= 0 && iLastY >= 0 && posX >= 0 && posY >= 0)
            {
                //Draw a red line from the previous point to the current point
                line(imgLines, Point(posX, posY), Point(iLastX, iLastY), Scalar(0, 0, 255), 2);
            }

            iLastX = posX;  //current point becomes last known point and loop continues
            iLastY = posY;
        }
        imshow("Thresholded Image", imgThresholded); //show the thresholded image   
        imgOriginal = imgOriginal + imgLines;
        imshow("Original", imgOriginal); //show the original image with the tracking lines if exist
        //External Cam code track/detect
        Mat imgHSV1;
        cvtColor(imgOriginal1, imgHSV1, COLOR_BGR2HSV); //Convert the captured frame from BGR to HSV
        Mat imgThresholded1;
        inRange(imgHSV1, Scalar(iLowH, iLowS, iLowV), Scalar(iHighH, iHighS, iHighV), imgThresholded1); //Threshold the image
        //morphological opening (removes noise and similar colored objects appearing in thresholded image)
        erode(imgThresholded1, imgThresholded1, getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(5, 5)));
        dilate(imgThresholded1, imgThresholded1, getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(5, 5)));
        //morphological closing (removes noise appearing inside our object in the thresholded image)
        dilate(imgThresholded1, imgThresholded1, getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(5, 5)));
        erode(imgThresholded1, imgThresholded1, getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(5, 5)));

        //Calculate the moments of the thresholded image to calculate the object position
        Moments oMoments1 = moments(imgThresholded1);
        double dM011 = oMoments1.m01;
        double dM101 = oMoments1.m10;
        double dArea1 = oMoments1.m00;

        // if the area <= 10000, I consider that the there are no object in the image and it's because of the noise, the area is not zero 
        if (dArea1 > 10000)
        {
            //calculate the position of the ball
            int posX1 = dM101 / dArea1;
            int posY1 = dM011 / dArea1;

            if (iLastX1 >= 0 && iLastY1 >= 0 && posX1 >= 0 && posY1 >= 0)
            {
                //Draw a red line from the previous point to the current point
                line(imgLines1, Point(posX1, posY1), Point(iLastX1, iLastY1), Scalar(0, 0, 255), 2);
            }

            iLastX1 = posX1;
            iLastY1 = posY1;
        }

        imshow("Thresholded Image 2", imgThresholded1); //show the thresholded image
        imgOriginal1 = imgOriginal1 + imgLines1;
        imshow("Original 2", imgOriginal1); //show the original image

        if (waitKey(30) == 27) //wait for 'esc' key press for 30ms. If 'esc' key is pressed, break loop
        {
            cout << "esc key is pressed by user" << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That second link has a link to a github page with source code. I don't understand that you couldn't have found that yet you said it does what you want to do ...

Comment: I am aware of that, but it requires installing additional software "Robot Operating System", but i also think it could be done in just Cpp and opencv.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question will be Stereo Vision. You need to do the Stereo Calibration of the two cameras in order to obtain the transformation matrix that allows to produce the depth map of the scene from the 2 views. OpenCV provides [some functions](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html) to do that.

[Here](http://www.jayrambhia.com/blog/stereo-calibration/) is a tutorial to begin with.